# Multiple references to the same dll in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, telerik, web-config

I have a web application (asp.net webforms) that uses telerik controls, such as telerik:ReportViewer and telerik:RadTimePicker.

The interesting part is, the telerik library extensively uses the same dll (e.g. System.Web.Extensions), causing IIS Manager to issue "Duplicate Reference" error. Trying to simply delete the duplicate references causes some parts of the website to stop working.

***How can I make same references to a single DLL within `Web.config`, without having to add duplicates??***

Look why:

```
<sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
                    <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
                    <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                    <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
                </sectionGroup>
            </sectionGroup>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
```

IIS reports duplicate references for each `section` element above. Deleting them causes the time picker to not show when clicked.

The same references goes in other places:

```
<compilation debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                ...
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                ...
                <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                ...
        </compilation>
```

And also:

```
<httpModules>
    <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</httpModules>

<modules>
    <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
    <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
</modules>
```

***When running using Visual Studio (Debugging), everything fine. But once deployed to IIS, IIS reports errors of duplicates!!***

Answer (score 1):

It seems your website has been updated from old .NET versions and has become a mess of sections that newer .NET versions do not need. VS does not really rung on IIS by default so it probably does not read the entire web.config, hence things working on dev.

So, what you can try is:

- start a new blank WebForms application targetting .NET 4 or .NET 4.5 , depending on what you target and copy its web.config. What you need to make sure is that you can run MS AJAX properly, so a simple asp:UpdatePanel on the page should let you have a working page first. This includes making sure all webresource requests pass.
- see what you need to add for Telerik's controls here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/web-config-settings-overview.html#mandatory-additions. It is just a few handlers, those sections that error out are used by the core MS AJAX functionality.
- try adding  **bindingRedirect** element for the old Web.Extensions assembly to the new one.